# What is the recommended approach to upload source maps to sentry from a next.js project

Tags: next.js, sentry, source-maps, vercel

## Summary:

- Hosting next.js application on Vercel
- Using sentry.io to monitor errors
- Trouble setting source maps up correctly

## Long Form:

A lot has changed since the early releases of sentry (where the sdk was called raven). Also a lot has changed with next.js and generating source maps is internalized and can be configured in the `next.config.js` as can be read [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/source-maps).

I am wondering what the correct (best-practice) approach is for uploading/providing source maps to sentry when deploying an application on vercel and why.

We do have the sentry documentation [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/sourcemaps/) but this is a little light and feels fairly generic/not next.js specific.

I do get issue reports in sentry, but they do not appear to include stack traces or where the error was thrown in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sentry’s Vercel Integration connects your Sentry and Vercel projects to automatically upload source maps and notify Sentry of release deployment.

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-sentry
- https://vercel.com/integrations/sentry
- https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/deployment/vercel/

Comment: I've been following these guides and I do see releases and commits being created but I do not see the source maps getting uploaded. Perhaps some security setting has changed?